# How to subclass a class with just a factory constructor?

Tags: dart

I want to subclass this class:

```dart
class FirebaseAuth {
  FirebaseAuth._(this.app);

  /// Provides an instance of this class corresponding to `app`.
  factory FirebaseAuth.fromApp(FirebaseApp app) {
    assert(app != null);
    return FirebaseAuth._(app);
  }

  /// Provides an instance of this class corresponding to the default app.
  static final FirebaseAuth instance = FirebaseAuth._(FirebaseApp.instance);

  final FirebaseApp app;
...
```

If I try to subclass it I get this error:

```dart
class FA extends FirebaseAuth {
  FA.fromApp(FirebaseApp app) : super.fromApp(app);
}
```

> The generative constructor 'FirebaseAuth FirebaseAuth.fromApp(FirebaseApp app)' expected, but factory found.  Try calling a different constructor in the superclass, or making the called constructor not be a factory constructor

I don't understand what it says, as far as I understand `FirebaseAuth.fromApp()` is not a generative constructor but a factory constructor. Also I can't see how I can subclass a generative constructor if all of them are private on the superclass.

Comment: "Also I can't see how I can subclass a generative constructor if all of them are private on the superclass." - you can't because you're not supposed to be able to.

Comment: Great haha so I can't extend it, so I will have to compose it I guess, thanks

Comment: "Composition over inheritance"!

Comment: Precisely, unfortunately inheritance would be better on my use case... I think I will actually send my code as a pull request to the FirebaseAuth repository.